# Are there Apple servers

Tags: macos, osx-server, hardware-virtualization

I know that a few companies like MacInCloud and even Microsoft offer services that run on some Apple-made OS -- maybe OSX. As far as I know, servers running an Apple-made OS must have the Apple label. Is Apple still making server hardware? If not, what are these companies using?

Comment: Apple retired there OS X Server many years ago

Comment: That's what I thought. What are these companies running then? MacInCloud is one exmaple but Microsoft also provides build services for Xamarin developers through Azure App Center and looks like they're running some type of Apple setup as well. I was just wondering what they're using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and no.

Apple did make server hardware called the Xserve.  However, it was discontinued in 2008.  We had some of these in an old job and they were definitely... interesting.

Today, people run macOS Server, formerly OS X Server.  It is a separately sold operating system add-on which provides additional server programs along with management and administration tools for macOS.  One would simply purchase the software through the Mac App Store and install it on their Mac... *Any* Mac.

Unfortunately, this means you are running a "server" OS (It is just OS X with more software) on a non-server class of hardware.  In high availability environments, most of the critical services would be run on Unix/Linux/Windows machines.

Comment: I see. Because macOS now runs on Intel microprocessors, it's not that difficult to find machines to run macOS Server on but what about Apple's licensing requirements? As far as I know, there must be an Apple label on the hardware for the OS to run.

Comment: @Sam It is against Apple's terms of service to run OS X on non Apple hardware.  And there is no Apple server hardware.

Comment: Oh, if I understand you correctly, these companies are running macOS server on Apple desktop/notebook hardware then. This way, they would not violate Apple licensing requirements.

Comment: @Sam Yes.  Apple doesnt compete in the server world, or really in its services.  They leave that to *NIX and Windows.  There isnt much that the macOS server software does that everyone else does better.  This gives small businesses the option to have those services in house on a spare Mac.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you but looks like Apple is now the old Microsoft. They have such crazy requirements. For example, any iOS app must be compiled and submitted from a Mac. So, in order to support developers like myself who are Windows based developers, companies like MacInCloud and Microsoft are coming up with solutions so that we can write the code on a Windows machine but handle the compilation on a Mac. I'm interested in using MacInCloud's services which is why I got curious about their setup.

Comment: @Sam I was just looking at their website.  They dont mention what their platform is.  From what I see, Im guessing its physical Macs.

Comment: I think so too. I just thought they may be using some type of Apple approved server hardware. Using actual Apple desktop/notebook would not only be very very very expensive but also hard to manage e.g. space, power, cable management, etc.

Comment: I can tell you one thing though, there's definitely a need for such a service, unless Apple changes their requirement to compile iOS apps on Macs.